# Importing Plugin Solution - An error has occurred. {1}{0}

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

Hy Guys,

My CRM System works fine since 15 months but now I got a very strange Error Message when I'm going to Import the latest Solutions with Assemblies and Plugin Steps.

The Error Message Shows only up following Text:

**An error has occurred. {1}{0}**

And thats all. After I looked up on the Event Viewer I got following strange message:

```C#
The Web Service plug-in failed in OrganizationId: e700006e-f815-e311-83b2-00155dce57c4; SdkMessageProcessingStepId: 227a2681-06e5-43ad-855a-aca4ebd20049; EntityName: none; Stage: 30; MessageName: GetComponents; AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin, Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
Inner Exception: System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
```

But I got about 10GB free space on my disk.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: this question doesn't belong to stackoverflow, I suggest to ask at Microsoft forums: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=crmdeployment

Comment: What's the size of your solution?

Comment: Long time ago I also got a weird error while importing the solution. I don't exactly remember the error but it was sorted after doing IISRESET. I think its worth trying.

Comment: The size of the solutions is about 20MB.

Comment: Have you turned on tracing? Last time I got a "disk is full"-error the problem was that the Activity feed wasn't available in the language I had chosen. Those error messages are far from flawless :)

Comment: Any chance that your database is full, rather than your web server?

Comment: After we splitted the solution down to 4 pieces and try Import it still works. Kind of strange that CRM can't handle Solutions up to 20 MB?!

Comment: There is a general max request limit in CRM which would affect not just solutions but any upload to CRM. If I'm not mistaken this limit is 8192. If you're getting a 20MB solution size I'd seriously take a look at what's in the file. Some perpetrators of incredibly large solution files are ZAP files that are probably not structured very well (often due to lack of re-use of files or large DLLs).

@GuidoPreite Many people come to stackoverflow to ask such questions on dynamics CRM. I think it's a perfectly fine forum to get a response.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems.

I resolved deleting all files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CustomizationImport

Best regards.

Comment: I ran into the same Problem again after the first Import of a 11MB Solution failed.
After deleting the Folder it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue within Internet Explorer 10 when importing a solution into CRM 2013 Online, I switched to Google Chrome and it imported without any issues.

Comment: Exactly same happened with me. I was trying to import an unmanaged solution on Dynamics CRM Online with IE10. Ended up with weird error message `An error has occurred. {1}{0}`. I switched the browser (to Chrome) and it imported successfully. Thanks Sunil.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete all files in SystemDrive:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CustomizationImport
- And also give grant read,write permissions on "SystemDrive:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CustomizationImport" folder to the user
  who is the identity of the crm application pool